# Scala Object Serialization

Tags: scala, serialization, scala-collections

I am having trouble opening multiple objects that were serialized into a single .bin file. Right now, I can only get one object to be read in when I attempt to open the file.  After the first object is read, the error message is displayed (and no further objects are read).  My code looks like the following:

```
val ois = new ObjectInputStream(new BufferedInputStream(newFileInputStream(chooser.selectedFile)))
val toRead:Int = ois.readInt()
    for (i <- 0 to toRead) {
      ois.readObject() match {
         case anObject : myObject =>
           aMutableBuffer += anObject
         case _ =>
      }
    ois.close()
    }
```

The error that I am getting is a lot of the following:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.security.PrivilegedActionException:java.security.PrivilegedActionException: java.io.IOException: Stream closed
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.AccessControlContext$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(AccessControlContext.java:87)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:649)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:296)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:211)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:196)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:188)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:122)
Caused by: java.security.PrivilegedActionException: java.io.IOException: Stream closed
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.AccessControlContext$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(AccessControlContext.java:87)
at java.security.AccessControlContext$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(AccessControlContext.java:98)
at java.awt.EventQueue$2.run(EventQueue.java:652)
at java.awt.EventQueue$2.run(EventQueue.java:650)
... 9 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Stream closed
at java.io.BufferedInputStream.getBufIfOpen(BufferedInputStream.java:145)
at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(BufferedInputStream.java:241)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream$PeekInputStream.peek(ObjectInputStream.java:2248)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream$BlockDataInputStream.peek(ObjectInputStream.java:2541)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream$BlockDataInputStream.peekByte(ObjectInputStream.java:2551)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1296)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:350)
atABCk.PhotoshopApp$$anonfun$ABCPhotoshopApp$$fileOpenPicture$1.apply$mcVI$sp(PhotoshopApp.scala:32)
at scala.collection.immutable.Range.foreach$mVc$sp(Range.scala:75)
at ABC.PhotoshopApp$.ABC$PhotoshopApp$$fileOpenPicture(PhotoshopApp.scala:31)
at ABC.PhotoshopApp$$anon$9$$anon$11$$anon$1$$anonfun$2.apply$mcV$sp(PhotoshopApp.scala:111)
at scala.swing.Action$$anon$2.apply(Action.scala:60)
at scala.swing.Action$$anon$1.actionPerformed(Action.scala:78)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2028)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2351)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:387)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:242)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton.doClick(AbstractButton.java:389)
at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicMenuItemUI.doClick(BasicMenuItemUI.java:809)
at com.apple.laf.AquaMenuItemUI.doClick(AquaMenuItemUI.java:137)
at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicMenuItemUI$Handler.menuDragMouseReleased(BasicMenuItemUI.java:913)
at javax.swing.JMenuItem.fireMenuDragMouseReleased(JMenuItem.java:568)
at javax.swing.JMenuItem.processMenuDragMouseEvent(JMenuItem.java:465)
at javax.swing.JMenuItem.processMouseEvent(JMenuItem.java:411)
at javax.swing.MenuSelectionManager.processMouseEvent(MenuSelectionManager.java:305)
at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicMenuItemUI$Handler.mouseReleased(BasicMenuItemUI.java:852)
at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6373)
at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3267)
at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6138)
at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2085)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4735)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2143)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4565)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4621)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4282)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4212)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2129)
at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2478)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4565)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:679)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$000(EventQueue.java:85)
at java.awt.EventQueue$1.run(EventQueue.java:638)
at java.awt.EventQueue$1.run(EventQueue.java:636)
... 14 more
```

This only happens when I read in an object to my buffer that keeps track of the objects.  Moreover, I am able to save the file correctly (as I have done tests to ensure everything got there).  Anyone have any ideas what is going on here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are closing your Stream `ois` at the end, but inside the loop. Then you try to read from it on the first line of the loop. Which obviously failes with a `IOException: Stream closed`

Comment: Wow... that was kind of stupid, hah.  Thanks for catching it!!

Comment: I guess we are all a little stupid. Thats why we let computer do all the important work ;-)

Comment: Exactly!! However, we have to tell them what to do correctly in order to get the important work done ;-).  Thanks again!!!